# Why the modifier on property is the same as Getter and Setter but not Field after Java being translated into Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

[Official Ref](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) says the default Visibility Modifier is public.

But from [koan data classes](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Data%20classes/Task.kt) it can be inferred that it is private.

Is it a contradiction? What is the default Visibility Modifier of property in kotlin?

---------The above is the initial question---------------

I didn't mix property and field up. But I did have confusion on **how property is accessed**.

To resolve my confusion, I actually should have asked the new question in edited title.

Self-answered below.

Comment: Properties are not fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What it the default Visibility Modifier for properties in kotlin?

It is public, as the docs say

## Why are the fields not private

In this example the fields are immutable, so there are no setters defined automatically. The data class automatically has getters, and uses them, but it simplifies reading the code by not requiring them to be manually called.

## Worked example

This code:

```
object X {
    data class Example(val a: String, val b: String)
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val e = Example("a", "b")
        println(e.a)
        println(e.b)
    }
}
```

The main method of this compiles to this (with checks and metadata removed):

```
public static final void main(String[] args) {
    X.Example e = new X.Example("a", "b");
    String var2 = e.getA();
    System.out.println(e.getA());
    var2 = e.getB();
    System.out.println(var2);
}
```

(Decompiled using IntelliJ IDEA)

Answer (score 5):

The default visibility for properties (and functions and classes, and...) is indeed public.

The Koan is a little confusing, because the Java class has private *fields* with public *getters*.
A property can be seen as the combination of field, a getter and an optional setter. The property in the Koan has a private *[backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields)* and a public getter.

If you for example write

```
val age = person.age
```

then Kotlin will basically generate a `getAge()` method of the `Person` class, that will be called internally. This method returns the field itself. 
It's also possible to add behavior to that getter. You can find more info in that in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters).

It's therefore not a contradiction, but a different concept.

Comment: A val field will have no setter

Comment: I honestly think that your own answer is even more confusing... But I'm out this discussion now. i'm glad you solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Property **encapsulates** backing field [by defintion](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields). **Backing field** is directly assigned **only** when being initialized. All accesses **except** initialization are done through **accessors**.

- So the private modifier on field **in Java** is no longer needed **in Kotlin**.
- And the public on getter and setter **in Java** is placed on property(actually, still for getter and setter) **in Kotlin**.

Therefore the omitted modifier is `public` and not `private`.

Comment: if you want to clarify your question, please edit the orginal post instead of posting an answer. if your question was answered by one of the proposed answers, then accept one of them.

Comment: But... your question has already been aswered by jratpsell (and me) or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't care about you accepting or not. Go ahead accept your own

Comment: I care whether SO as a tool is used in a way that it helps others (not only the person who asked the question). You seem to be under the impression (it's in your profile), that SO is _"99% hostile downvoters"_  but it seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding on how this site works :-/